# Openstack, Connecting to nova, error: Cannot initiate connection

Tags: server, ssh, openstack

I am new to Openstack, I've installed it using devstack. I launched an instance using ubuntu server cloud image with heat flavor. I can ssh to the instance. The problem is when trying to do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I have

> 0% (connecting to nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com ip@)

It keeps changing the ip@ then error cannot initiate connection to nova connect(101: network unreachable)